# How to add a dynamic variable to the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I need to dynamically insert an array (=> inputClasses) String (=> 'Invalid') which is actually a class from css. And then from the HTML tag to read the two of them together.
The problem is he doesn't give me both.
What's my mistake?

```
import React from 'react';
import './Input.css';

const input = (props) => {
    let inputElement = null;
    const inputClasses = ['InputElement'];

    if (props.invalid) {
        inputClasses.push('Invalid');
    }

    switch (props.elementType) {
        case ('input'):
            inputElement = <input
                className={inputClasses.join()}       <---------- Here he does not give me both
                {...props.elementConfig}
                defaultValue={props.value}
                onChange={props.changed} />;
            break;
        case ('textarea'):
            inputElement = <textarea
                className={inputClasses.join()}       <---------- And Here he does not give me both
                {...props.elementConfig}
                defaultValue={props.value}
                onChange={props.changed} />;
            break;
        case ('select'):
            inputElement = ( 
                <select
                    className={inputClasses.join()}         <---------- And Here he does not give me both
                    defaultValue={props.value}
                    onChange={props.changed}>
                    {props.elementConfig.options.map(option => (
                        <option key={option.value} defaultValue={option.value}>
                            {option.displayValue}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </select>
            );
            break;
        default:
            inputElement = <input
                className={inputClasses.join()}      <---------- And Here he does not give me both
                {...props.elementConfig}
                defaultValue={props.value}
                onChange={props.changed} />;
    }

    return (
        <div className="Input">
            <label className="Label">{props.label}</label>
            {inputElement}
        </div>
    );
};

export default input;
```

I appreciate every answer!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You gotta have a space between your class names, not a comma

```
inputClasses.join(' ')
```